# Are while loops not usable in Swing applications?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Basically I have a game board and I want to make it illegal to make the first move on a square that is not on an edge. The frame is a 5x5 gameboard that alternates its color on click depending on whose turn it is.

MY PROBLEM: When I start the program, it does not tell me that the buttons that I am pressing in the middle are illegal moves. Can anyone explain why the code is not working?

Here is some sample code:

```
package fgame;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class FooFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Color whoseTurn = Color.BLACK;
private Color playerOneTurn = Color.BLACK;
private Color playerTwoTurn = Color.ORANGE;
private String playerOne = "You";
private String playerTwo;
private int PlayerOneCount = 21;
private int PlayerTwoCount = 21;


public FooFrame() {
    initComponents();
    setSize(800,800);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    humanOrAI();
    movesLeft();
    endGame();


}

private void humanOrAI()
{
    Object[] options = {"Other Human","Computer (EASY)","Computer (HARD)"};

    Object input = (Object) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Who is your opponent?",
            "CHOOSE YOUR FATE!",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,options,
            options[0]);  
    if (input == options[0]){
        playerTwo = (String.valueOf(options[0]));
    }
    else if (input == options[1]){
        playerTwo = (String.valueOf(options[1]));   
    }
    else {
        playerTwo = (String.valueOf(options[2]));
    }        
}

private void determineWhoseTurn()
{
    if (whoseTurn.equals(playerOneTurn))
    {
        whoseTurn = Color.orange;
    }
    else
    {
        whoseTurn = Color.BLACK;
    }
}

public void movesLeft()
{

    if (whoseTurn.equals(playerOneTurn))
    {
        jLabel1.setText(" " + playerOne + " have " + PlayerOneCount+ " pieces left    "
                + "         "+ playerTwo+ " has " + PlayerTwoCount+ " pieces left");
        PlayerOneCount--;
    }

    else
    {
        jLabel1.setText(" " + playerOne + " have " + PlayerOneCount+ " pieces left    "
                + "         "+ playerTwo+ " has " + PlayerTwoCount+ " pieces left");
        PlayerTwoCount--;
    }  
}

//How do I count the amount of black and orange squares?
public void endGame()
{
    int black = 0;
    int orange = 0;

    if (whoseTurn.equals(playerOneTurn))
    {
        black++;
    }
    else
    {
        orange++;
    }

    if (PlayerTwoCount <= 0 || PlayerOneCount <= 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Game Over!" + " black: "+ black
        + "orange: "+ orange);
    }
}

public void validStartingPoint()
{
   Object illStartPoint[] = {B2,B3,B4,C2,C3,C4,D2,D3,D4};

   while (PlayerOneCount == 21 || PlayerTwoCount == 21)
       if (whoseTurn.equals(illStartPoint[0-8]))
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Not a valid move! Start "
                   + "from an edge square!");
       } else
       {
           break;
       }
}
```

My question pertains to the method validStartingPoint(). But I also had a question about endGame() as well that is put in a comment above it. ALL METHODS ARE CALLED IN ALL MY JBUTTONS

Also, I am aware that this could have nothing to do with the while loop. I am not the best coder in the world.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you're asking. Obviously its fine to use loops in your code, and I don't see any other question here. I don't even see a description of what is happening that you don't expect.

Comment: Your main question is trivial: of course while loops are applicable in Swing applications, but your underlying question is not and in fact is incomplete. You tell us nothing about the problems your code is having nor have you posted anything we can run. Please consider improving this question and providing a [mcve] (not in a link mind you), and we'll have a better ability to find an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have added more code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels did not suggest 'more code' but an MCVE! Please follow and read the link.. Thje code seen would need imports and a `main(String[])` method to put it on-screen before it could be called an MCVE.

Comment: I can't run or even compile your code, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: You state `"When I start the program, it does not tell me that the buttons that I am pressing in the middle are illegal moves."` -- based on your code above, your buttons should tell you nothing, since you've not added ActionLIsteners to anything. In fact I don't see any JButtons declared anywhere in the code above. I'm still at a loss.

Comment: See edits to answer for more. I'm trying to understand your code,....

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to give you specific help as your question as written is incomplete, but to answer your direct question: while loops are of course applicable in Swing applications,

**BUT**, you shouldn't use them as you would in a linear console application. Understand that Swing GUI's, like most GUI's are not linear programs where one bit of code necessarily follows another, but rather they are **event**-driven programs, where code often is only called after an event -- such as a button press, or a mouse press occurs.

So you'll not want to use a while loop to await or poll for user input, but rather will want to use a "state" machine type design and listen for events, with the state being the state of the underlying model for your program, here your game logic.

If you need more detailed help, then please flesh out your question including creating and posting a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to work with.

---

if these guys are JButtons, then yes, the while loop is wrong

```
Object illStartPoint[] = { B2, B3, B4, C2, C3, C4, D2, D3, D4 };
```

Instead, the button's ActionListener should have an if statement within it, that checks on button press if the button press is legal. This will depend on what part of the program  you're in, so that must be part of the boolean statement within the if test that determines if it's legal or not. For instance if you're preventing someone from pressing a button on the first button press, a few booleans would do it.

But having said that, I would actually do things differently. I would inactivate any buttons that shouldn't be pressed, and then would activate them when/if they should be pressed. This can be done by calling `setEnabled(boolean enabled)` and passing in true or false for that button depending on what state the program is in.

For instance, run this code to see what I mean:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestButtons1 extends JPanel {
    private static final int BUTTON_COUNT = 10;
    // private boolean onlyEvenButtonsActve = true;
    private List<JButton> allButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    public TestButtons1() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("Button " + i);
            // add ActionListener
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                System.out.println("Button pressed: " + e.getActionCommand());
            });

            buttonPanel.add(button);  // add to jpanel 
            allButtons.add(button); // add to array list for all buttons
        }

        JToggleButton activateOnlyEvensTglBtn = new JToggleButton("Activate Only Even Buttons");
        activateOnlyEvensTglBtn.addItemListener(e -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < allButtons.size(); i++) {
                boolean b = i % 2 == 0  || e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED;
                allButtons.get(i).setEnabled(b);
            }
        });
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(activateOnlyEvensTglBtn);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestButtons1 mainPanel = new TestButtons1();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestButtons1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```